# Orchard CMS. Can a viewmodel be passed to a custom error page?

Tags: exception, viewmodel, orchardcms

Can a viewmodel be passed to a custom error page?

Not sure if this is possible as the error page throws an exception.

```
public ActionResult ErrorPage()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

This would be useful so that I don't have to access the WorkContext within the errorPage view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to `Model.Message` and `Model.Exception` from the template code, which is really all you need, given that you can create your own exception types.